# How do i get a full image as background of my header in html/css?

Tags: html, css

When i choose a image to put as a background of my div i can't manage to make it look normal. The width and height of my header are made with em. Can someone explain me how i can get a image as a background at my header when the header is like: 120em width. 5em height. So i need to make a normal header background the size of my header.

```
.header{
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
background-image:url('images.jpg');
text-align: center;
width: 120em;
height:5em;
background-size:100%;
}

.left{
background-color:red;
float: left;
width: 20em;
height: 51em;
}

.middle{
background-color: green;
width:120em;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
height:51em;
}

.footer{
height:4em;
width: 120em;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with setting your divs height and width in pixels so you can set the header same size as is your background picture?

Comment: Yes because when i run it on a different resolution, the divs will mess up.

Comment: I mean the divs will mess up.

Answer (score 5):

Check here, http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/PtEnY/3/

```
#yourHeader{
  float:left;
  width:120em;
  height:5em; 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg); 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I mean a normal sized header background fitting in my header. How does it work? Now it's only showing a little bit of the header.

Comment: what is your header bg size? Are you using font-size with pixel or percentage in body. Then, calculate your header bg in pixel, reference here http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Yes, if you don't want fix bg, remove it. What we are talking here is about background-size: cover;.. Your background-size:100%; doesn't effect anything. Only background-size: cover; does.

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbo-background { 
  background: url(image/bg.jpg) no-repeat center/cover; 
}
```

I think I understand what you are try to achieve, the above is what I use, just drop it on the highest level div where you want the background image and it should stay relatively "in frame" as the page scales. You way want to add a bit to this for compatibility but the above is the general gist.