# Linking Img as my background under Header for CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have tried to use an image under my header tag and my image will not appear. I used MDN's HTML & CSS reference:

```html
<header class="page-header">
<h1>Cute Puppies Express!</h1>
</header>
```

```css
header.page-header {
    background: no-repeat left/cover url(/media/examples/puppy-header-logo.jpg);
    display: flex;
}
```

My root folder "Amei New" contains my HTML, CSS & Images.
I have tried background: url("./images/diversewomen.jpg");
And after CTRL clicking that url, it lead me to the image I am using, but does not show on my browser.

I also have tried adding ../images/diversewomen.jpg, used single, double, or no quotes, and none of them worked.

I have attached my code.[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgRDJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get a full image as background of my header in html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145357/how-do-i-get-a-full-image-as-background-of-my-header-in-html-css)

Answer (score 0):

hope this wil solve your problem

```
background-image:url("/media/examples/puppy-header-logo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is different from the text you posted.

In the image the problem is the reference : **"header .home_page" -> "header.home_page"** because the class is refered to header it self.

In the post not error occured apparently if the url is correct.

In every case, the '/' at the start of a route is right, because indicate to the link to start from the root directory. The dot is needed for exit/enter from directories.

This is a try (the blue is a random background from internet): [image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet using some of your code, comments are in the CSS.

Also, referring to the file structure in your screenshot you can call the image like this `./diversewomen.jpg` since it's contained within the same root folder.

Example: `background-image: url("./diversewomen.jpg");`

```css
header.page-header {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/23/14/38/adorable-3344414__340.jpg"); /*change this url to your image url*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto; /*change to your preferred size*/
    height: 500px; /*change this to your preferred height*/
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
<h1>Cute Puppies Express!</h1>
</header>
```